# Orientation-preserving isometric involution on compact Kähler manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact Kähler manifold. If $\phi:M\to M$ is an orientation-preserving isometric involution does it have to be either holomorphic or anti-holomorphic?

Comment: Let $X$ be a Kaehler manifold with an antiholomorphic involution $i$ that is isometric.  On the product $X\times X$, consider the product of the identity map and $i$.

Comment: The holonomy of the metric preserves the complex structure, since it is Kaehler. By the de Rham splitting theorem, and the Berger classification of holonomy groups, either the universal covering space splits isometrically into a product, or else the holonomy group determines the complex structure, i.e. does not sit inside two conjugates of the unitary group inside the rotation group.

Comment: @JasonStarr:  Your construction might not preserve the orientation of the product, since $i$ might not be orientation preserving.

Comment: @BenMcKay:  Actually, even if the holonomy is irreducible, the holonomy group may not determine the complex structure.  For example, if the metric is hyperKähler, then there will be at least a 2-sphere of complex structures compatible with the metric.

Comment: I wish the standard definition of Kaehler was 'holonomy $U_n$'. So many questions would have neater answers.

Comment: @PaulReynolds:  Really?  You wouldn't want the Ricci-flat metric on K3 constructed by Yau to be called 'Kähler', or the product of two Kähler metrics to be called 'Kähler'?

Comment: @RobertBryant, I guess I wish I didn't have to keep writing 'assume full holonomy' or similar, as I think would make sense for the question above as well as other isometry questions. I won't argue with you though, because I would not win that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Let $M$ be the product of three copies of $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}[i])$ (i.e., the square torus).  Give it the obvious product metric.  Now consider the map
$$
\phi\bigl([z_1],[z_2],[z_3]\bigr) = \bigl([z_1],[\,\overline{z_2}\,],[\,\overline{z_3}\,]\bigr).
$$
This is an orientation-preserving isometry that is neither holomorphic nor antiholomorphic.

Comment: More generally, in the spirit of Jason's comment, could we take $\mathrm{id} \times f \times f$ on $X \times X \times X$, where $X$ is compact Kaehler and $f \colon X \to X$ is an anti-holomorphic isometric involution?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi:  Yes, of course, though, perhaps just as simple:  Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are compact Kähler and that $Y$ has even complex dimension and an antiholomorphic isometric involution $f$ and take $\mathrm{id}_X{\times} f : X{\times} Y\to X{\times}Y$.